# Relationship between $\left\Vert A-B \right\Vert$ and $\left\Vert A_s- B_s \right\Vert$ where $A$ is similar to $A_s$ and $B$ is similar to $B_s$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, upper-lower-bounds, matrix-analysis

I'm looking for a bound that relates $\left\Vert A-B \right\Vert_{op}$ and $\left\Vert A_s- B_s \right\Vert_{op}$ where $A$ and $A_s$ are similar matrices and $B$ and $B_s$ are similar matrices. If it helps one can assume that all four matrices are real and that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric (but $A_s$ and $B_s$ may not be). I define the matrix norm here as the operator norm induced by the Euclidian norm.

It is easy to check these quantities are not equal. Is it possible to construct a bound of the form $$\left\Vert A-B \right\Vert_{op} \leq f\left\Vert A_s- B_s \right\Vert_{op}$$
where $f$ is a variable that depends on the matrices in question?

Comment: I was going to write an answer but realised your $c$ is not constant at all. Why not take $c=\|A-B\|/\|A_s-B_s\|$ ?

Comment: Because it doesn't give me insight into the relationship, I'd much prefer something in terms of the norms of the individual matrices if possible. I've edited the question to hopefully make it clearer that $c$ is not a constant

Comment: As @Chrystomath 's example shows there is no such estimate. $\|A_s\|=\|A\|$, $\|B_s\|=\|B\|$, and you can make $\|A_s- B_s\|=0$ regardless of what those norms are, just scale the matrices there. To put it crudely, there is no relationship: $A_s$ and $B_s$ are representations of $A$ and $B$ in different bases, so whatever the $A$ to $B$  relationship was comparing $A_s$ to $B_s$ is like comparing apples to oranges. Think of a simple analogy: given two vectors what is the relationship between their rotated versions without any restriction on the rotations involved?

Comment: Makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=B_s=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $A$ is similar to $$A_s:=B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}A\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

As $\|A-B\|=\|\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\|=\sqrt2$ but $A_s-B_s=0$, there is no number $c$ such that $\|A-B\|\le c\|A_s-B_s\|$.